# Cypress access alias with this.* doesn't works even with function

Tags: cypress

Trying to access the alias value on the this () Context, I followed the docs from https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as#Fixture

In the .then callback the dataExample parameter is filled OK, but on this.example it is undefined.

```js
describe('cy.as and this', function () {

  it('Testing cy.as and this', function () {

    cy.fixture('example.json').as('example')
      .then(function (dataExample) {
        cy.log('ACCESSING this, dataExample', this, dataExample);
      });

    cy.log(`ACCESSING this.example : ${JSON.stringify(this['example'])}`, this);
  });

});
```

The first log outputs the following: with the dataExample correctly filled, but the contex.example undefined
[image: logging this and dataExample in the .then]

The second log outside of .then, with this.example also undefined
[image: this]

If I move the cy.fixture line into a beforeEach() it does work. Cold somebody explain this behavior?

```js
describe('alias', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.fixture('example.json').as('example');
  });

  it('can access all aliases as properties', function () {
    expect(this['example']).not.to.eq(undefined); // true
    cy.log('THIS', this); // curious =>  [0]: Context {_runnable: undefined, test: undefined, example: undefined}
    cy.log('THIS.example', this['example']); // {name: 'Using fixtures to represent data', email: 'hello@cypress.io',
                                             // body: 'Fixtures are a great way to mock data for responses to routes'}
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

A helpful way to think of the flow is that there are two passes:

- first pass, runs the javascript of the test and executes plain JS but ***enqueues*** Cypress commands (and their callbacks)
- second pass executes those commands

So when

```js
cy.log(`ACCESSING this.example : ${JSON.stringify(this['example'])}`, this)
```

is enqueued in the first pass, the parameter `this['example']` is evaluated immediately (value is **undefined**).

It's not storing the parameter ***expression*** to be evaluated in the second pass, which is what most people expect.

But you can defer the parameter evaluation by putting it inside another callback.

```js
cy.then(() => {
  // this callback code is enqueued
  // so the evaluation of "this['example']" is deferred until the queue is running
  cy.log(`ACCESSING this.example : ${JSON.stringify(this['example'])}`, this)
})
```

Gleb Bahmutov has a blog
[How to replace the confusing cy.then command with the less confusing cy.later command](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/replace-and-remove-cy-then-command/)

Answer (score 1):

Cypress commands are asynchronous. Cypress does not execute a command immediately, it just puts one into a queue to be executed lately. So any command inside a single block of code will not be executed in this block. And the *other* block of code means any of this:

1. other `it` test
2. `before`/`beforeAll`/`after`/`afterAll` hooks
3. `then`/`should` callback

So if you want to use a value from a cypress command inside  the same `it` test, you have to use a `then` callback in order to give Cypress time to execute the command.

If you use a cypress command in a `beforeEach` hook, the command will be executed by the time when `it` code starts.

Comment: As you said, in a then callback it should be ok because executed in the flow.
Same goes for another cy.anyCommand() because the anyCommand will be execued later as well.
So the ${JSON.stringify(this['example']) should not see the example value because it is not yet here and the parameter of cy.log are resolved before the execution, but passing the this to the cy.log second parameter should be correct. cy.log will execute  it later in the flow, and at that time the this.example is supposed to be already filled.