# Cypress.env is empty after setup

Tags: javascript, cypress

Hi I have such function and after setup my Cypress.env variable is empty how can I resolve it? But I worked with Cypress in such way before and it was good

Cypress version - 10.10
Cypress config - default

```
static checkPriceForQuantityOfProductInCart()
{
    cy.get(totalPrice).eq(1).invoke('text').then((text => { 
        Cypress.env('PRICE', text) 
        cy.log(Cypress.env('PRICE')) // 125.00
    }))
    cy.log(Cypress.env('PRICE')) //undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Cypress access alias with this.* doesn't works even with function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74130516/18366749).

You can wrap the `cy.log()` in a callback

```js
static checkPriceForQuantityOfProductInCart()
{
    cy.get(totalPrice).eq(1).invoke('text').then((text => { 
        Cypress.env('PRICE', text) 
        cy.log(Cypress.env('PRICE')) // 125.00
    }))
    .then(() => {
      cy.log(Cypress.env('PRICE')) // 125.00
    })
}
```

Or

```js
static checkPriceForQuantityOfProductInCart()
{
    cy.get(totalPrice).eq(1).invoke('text').then((text => { 
        Cypress.env('PRICE', text) 
        cy.log(Cypress.env('PRICE')) // 125.00
    }))

    cy.then(() => {
      cy.log(Cypress.env('PRICE')) // 125.00
    })
}
```